# How to index the Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, database

I am sure this is a textbook question but i just cannot get this right. Consider having a collection of 10M Mongodb documents like this:

```
{
    prop1 : "a selective string property",
    prop2 : "another selective string property",
    attribs : [
        {
            k : 'attribute name',
            v : 'short string value'
        },

        {
            k : 'another attribute name',
            v : 'short string value'
        }
   ],
   sortKey1 : "a short string being sorted on",
   sortKey2 : "another short string being sorted on"
}
```

- `attribs` array holds arbitrary but small amount of attributes, say less then 20.
- `attribs.k` is the name of the attribute. There is an unknown but still small amount of such names say less then 200.
- `attribs.v` is the value the attribute with name `attribs.k`
- It is hard to judge on the selectivity of either `attribs.k` or `attribs.v`

Typical queries against this collections are a combination of range (`$in`, `$lt`, etc) or equality on `prop1`, `prop2` and `attribs`. There can be multiple `$and` conditions on the `attribs` field in the query. Results are sorted on either `sortKey1` or `sortKey2`.

And the big question is of course how to create indexes so that that any query as above is properly supported by an index.

Real world example - a shop: Find all cars located in cities X, Y, Z manufactured by either K, L or M with mileage between 50k and 150k with cruise control, xenon lights, automatic transmission and itself being red green or blue.

Solutions using other NoSQL dbs are welcomed, though Mongodb answer is preferred. Suggestions to change the schema are also OK.